C# Make standalone or place output files in a SubFolder
I want to build my project as standalone .exe or place all the files it comes with it in a sub folder.
Build info: C#, .NET Framework with Visual Studio 2019 Community edition.
When I build my project it outputs these files:
Myapp.exe (of course)
Myapp.exe.config (I know this needs to be with the .exe)
Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.dll
Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.xml

I know I can build it with fody Costura to integrate the Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.dll and that works but it still got .exe.config and the Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.xml.
Maybe I don't need both there isn't much going on in the config file but do I need the Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.xml?
If so is it possible to add the Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.xml and the .exe.config into the .exe also?
If it's not possible to make 1 single .exe with no extra files, I thought that it would be handy to place all the files in a subfolder like (/Config) except myapp.exe.
It would look like this then:
/Config   
  - Myapp.exe.config   
  - Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.dll   
  - Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.xml 
Myapp.exe

Hope someone can help me with this problem.
.exe.config (removed token and appname):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="myappnamehere" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=tokenhere" >           
            <section name="myapp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=tokenhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="myappnamehere.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=tokenhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>

Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.xml a piece from the code - it's very large:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialogItemCollection`1">
            <summary>
            Represents a list of <see cref="T:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialogItem"/> objects.
            </summary>
            <typeparam name="T">The type of the task dialog item.</typeparam>
            <threadsafety instance="false" static="true"/>
        </member>
        <member name="M:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialogItemCollection`1.ClearItems">
            <summary>
            Overrides the <see cref="M:System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.ClearItems"/> method.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialogItemCollection`1.InsertItem(System.Int32,`0)">
            <summary>
            Overrides the <see cref="M:System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.InsertItem(System.Int32,`0)"/> method.
            </summary>
            <param name="index">The zero-based index at which <paramref name="item"/> should be inserted.</param>
            <param name="item">The object to insert. May not be <see langword="null"/>.</param>
            <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="item"/> is <see langword="null"/>.</exception>
            <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">The <see cref="T:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialogItem"/> specified in <paramref name="item"/> is already associated with a different task dialog.</exception>
            <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">The <see cref="T:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialogItem"/> specified in <paramref name="item"/> has a duplicate id or button type.</exception>
            <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
            <para>
              <paramref name="index"/> is less than zero.
            </para>
            <para>
              -or-
            </para>
            <para>
              <paramref name="index"/> is equal to or greater than <see cref="P:System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Count"/>.
            </para>
            </exception>
        </member>
        <member name="M:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialogItemCollection`1.RemoveItem(System.Int32)">
            <summary>
            Overrides the <see cref="M:System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.RemoveItem(System.Int32)"/> method.
            </summary>
            <param name="index">The zero-based index of the element to remove.</param>
            <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
            <para>
              <paramref name="index"/> is less than zero.
            </para>
            <para>
              -or-
            </para>
            <para>
              <paramref name="index"/> is equal to or greater than <see cref="P:System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Count"/>.
            </para>
            </exception>
        </member>
        <member name="M:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialogItemCollection`1.SetItem(System.Int32,`0)">
            <summary>
            Overrides the <see cref="M:System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.SetItem(System.Int32,`0)"/> method.
            </summary>
            <param name="index">The zero-based index of the element to replace.</param>
            <param name="item">The new value for the element at the specified index. May not be <see langword="null"/>.</param>
            <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="item"/> is <see langword="null"/>.</exception>
            <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">The <see cref="T:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialogItem"/> specified in <paramref name="item"/> is already associated with a different task dialog.</exception>
            <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">The <see cref="T:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.TaskDialogItem"/> specified in <paramref name="item"/> has a duplicate id or button type.</exception>
            <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
            <para>
              <paramref name="index"/> is less than zero.
            </para>
            <para>
              -or-
            </para>
            <para>
              <paramref name="index"/> is equal to or greater than <see cref="P:System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Count"/>.
            </para>
            </exception>
        </member>
        <member name="T:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Properties.Resources">
            <summary>
              A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager">
            <summary>
              Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Properties.Resources.Culture">
            <summary>
              Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
              resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Properties.Resources.AnimationLoadErrorFormat">
            <summary>
              Looks up a localized string similar to Unable to load the progress dialog animation: {0}.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Properties.Resources.CredentialEmptyTargetError">
            <summary>
              Looks up a localized string similar to The credential target may not be an empty string..
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Properties.Resources.CredentialError">
            <summary>
              Looks up a localized string similar to An error occurred acquiring credentials..
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Properties.Resources.CredentialPromptNotCalled">
            <summary>
              Looks up a localized string similar to PromptForCredentialsWithSave has not been called or the credentials were modified after the call..
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Properties.Resources.DuplicateButtonTypeError">
            <summary>
              Looks up a localized string similar to The task dialog already has a non-custom button with the same type..
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Properties.Resources.DuplicateItemIdError">
            <summary>
              Looks up a localized string similar to The task dialog already has an item with the same id..
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Properties.Resources.FileNotFoundFormat">
            <summary>
              Looks up a localized string similar to The file &quot;{0}&quot; could not be found..
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.Properties.Resources.FolderBrowserDialogNoRootFolder">
            <summary>
              Looks up a localized string similar to Unable to retrieve the root folder..
            </summary>
        </member>

What i already did in short:
Fody Costura for the Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.dll, it works but still got the other files.
To place the dll in a sub folder this code also works but only for dll files...:
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="Config" />
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>



You do not need the xml, it can be safely removed. 2. You may want to consider migrating from net framework to net8, then use single-file publishing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli)


Oke, thanks and for the .exe.config do i need to keep it also with that little of code in it? And indeed maybe if i got time in the future i will migrating to net 8.

About .exe.config - it depends. It can contain runtime switches and other settings that will affect the behaviour of your code. But if  it does not contain any settings (as in your sample), I think it can be deleted.

Oke, Yes that is the full .exe.config. Oke for now i will use Fody Costura to embedding the dll and remove all the other files. Thank you very much for the help!
Ow by the way i already tried to migrate to .Net8 just to see how it works but i got to many errors in the code so i will update this app to .Net framework 4.8 for now and maybe in the future i will look again to .Net8. Anyway Thanks again for the help.

Solution:
Big thanks and shoutout to @Serg and to @marc_s for making my Question better to read with the codes and stuff!
So if you got the same question as i did here is how to fix it:
Use Fody Costura to embed the dlls and you can delete Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.xml.
For the .exe.config check if it used for something in my case its not so i can delete it and works without it else leave the config file with you .exe.
It is also possible to migrate to .Net 8 with Visual studio 2022 however in my project i got to many code errors.
If you would like to try it, here is the how to.
